# IMAP Search Command with date filter

Tags: c#, imap, gmail-imap

I am trying to get UID list of mails in a particular date range.
Am trying to perform the below command

$ UID SEARCH SINCE 24-april-2017 BEFORE 27-april-2017 UID 1:*

Getting exception as BAD COMMAND.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for month is:

```
date-month      = "Jan" / "Feb" / "Mar" / "Apr" / "May" / "Jun" /
                  "Jul" / "Aug" / "Sep" / "Oct" / "Nov" / "Dec"
```

So your command ought to be

```
$ uid search since 24-apr-2017 before 27-apr-2017 uid 1:*
* SEARCH 317556 317557 [...] 318139 318140
$ OK done
```

Or just `$ uid search since 24-apr-2017 before 27-apr-2017` since the UID restriction is a no-op.

Comment: In that case, you are supposed to accept the answer.